# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters

Tags: php

Hi I am new in using `PDO` and I encounter this problem on 1 of my table containing more than 10 fields

Here the table design:

```
id  Primary     int(11)             No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   sid     varchar(15)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
3   courseCode  varchar(15) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
4   isScholar   varchar(15) latin1_swedish_ci       No  Non-Scholar         
5   course  varchar(25)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
6   level   varchar(15)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
7   fname   varchar(25)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
8   lname   varchar(25)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
9   mi      varchar(5)      latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
10  age     int(3)                                  No  None        
11  gender  varchar(15)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
12  bday    date                                    No  None        
13  cNumber varchar(15)      atin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
14  email   varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
15  address varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
16  regDate datetime                                No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       
17  regBy   varchar(50)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
18  updatedDate     datetime                        Yes     NULL        
19  updatedBy   varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes     NULL        
20  status  varchar(15)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  ACTIVE      
21  userType    varchar(15) latin1_swedish_ci       No  STUDE
```

And here is my code for inserting data to table via `PHP` file:

[image: this is my code]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Couple things to improve your question, once you are done posting it, come back to it and look if it is readable.  Your section for table design was a large dump of text, without indentation.  You can format these as code and align your columns properly.  As for your code, since it is text, it *must* be pasted in here as text.  Then format it as code with the `{}` icon on top of the editor.  Read [ask], [mcve] and take the tour for new users.

Comment: your missing the isScholar field from your stmt between courseCode and course fields.

Comment: Session_start() doesn't need the STFU operator (`@`). We prefer code as text, not images.  Part of your query is "off-screen". We can only assume the missing text.

Answer (score 1):

`bindparam()`, according to the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php uses indexes (from `1`) when using `?` placeholders; or use the colon-prefixed syntax with named placeholders.

You also need to make sure you are binding every placeholder with a value/variable.

You might rather enjoy the less verbose syntax of using `?` placeholders and delivering an array of variables as a parameter of `execute()`.